# Is it possible to display an image over a photo taken in app

Tags: ios

Is it possible to have a series of images (pngs) that can be positioned either over the top of an image taken in app or just appear on the screen when in camera mode in app? ie a door or wallpaper sample.

If so how might this be achieved?

Thanks for any help given :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

```
-(IBAction)loadCameraView:(id)sender
{

   if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

 if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])

    {
        [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];

    }
    else
    {
        [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear];

    }
    [imagePicker setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *aview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [aview show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`UIImagePickerController` has a `cameraOverlayView` `UIView` property. Assign it whatever you want to be on top of the camera.

From the docs:

> > You can use an overlay view to present a custom view hierarchy on top of the default image picker interface. The image picker layers your custom overlay view on top of the other image picker views and positions it relative to the screen coordinates. If you have the default camera controls set to be visible, incorporate transparency into your view, or position it to avoid obscuring the underlying content.